# Display folder found through keyword search

Tags: vba, search, outlook

Here is the existing code to search by looping through all Outlook folder names, using a keyword, to return a folder name.

I would like the option to select an outcome (folder's name) and be directed to that folder in the folder explore window.

```vb
Sub SearchFolders() 
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim keyword As String
    ' Set keyword
    keyword = InputBox("Enter the keyword:")
    ' Set namespace
    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ' Loop through all folders
    For Each myFolder In myNamespace.Folders
        Call LoopFolders(myFolder, keyword)
    Next
End Sub

Sub LoopFolders(ByVal myFolder As Outlook.folder, ByVal keyword As String)
    Dim mySubFolder As Outlook.folder
    ' Check if folder name contains keyword
    If InStr(1, myFolder.Name, keyword, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print myFolder.Name
    End If
    ' Loop through all subfolders
    For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.Folders
        Call LoopFolders(mySubFolder, keyword)
    Next
End Sub

Sub SearchFolders1()
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim keyword As String
    ' Set keyword
    keyword = InputBox("Enter the keyword:")
    ' Set namespace
    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ' Loop through all folders
    For Each myFolder In myNamespace.Folders
        Call LoopFolders(myFolder, keyword)
    Next
End Sub

Sub LoopFolders1(ByVal myFolder As Outlook.folder, ByVal keyword As String)
    Dim mySubFolder As Outlook.folder
    ' Check if folder name contains keyword
    If InStr(1, myFolder.Name, keyword, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print myFolder.Name
    End If
    ' Loop through all subfolders
    For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.Folders
        Call LoopFolders(mySubFolder, keyword)
    Next
End Sub
```